# Is there a foolproof way to change the selection color in a WinRT ListView?

Tags: listview, windows-8, windows-runtime

All of the other answers I have seen say "Edit the template, change the selected and pressed states."  I did just that, and *still* the ListView turns purple on highlight and select.  I even tried modifying every state that I found purple in and **still** it turned purple.  Struggling over such a simple thing is infuriating.  In fact, when I changed all the purple ones to gray then it simply just stopped showing up, and eventually turned purple if I click it twice in a row.

Could someone show me how to correctly change the ugly purple selection color of the ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it.  Turns out I don't have to change any of the actual states.  They all use the same base color, and just animate opacities.  So, changing the base color to gray was enough.  Just go through the hierarchy (without selecting a certain state) and look for things that need to be changed or hidden and set appropriately.

Comment: I opened the file in Blend and copied the template like the other answer said, but then instead of editing the states, I simply went through the objects and found things like "selection background" that were purple and changed them to gray (or just changed their visibility to collapsed)